# Access anaconda modules from global to virtual env

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I have successfully installed the Anaconda distribution to the default path (which includes pandas) for Python 3.7 following instructions on [anaconda documentation](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install/linux/). 
Pandas import runs successfully after loading the base env that was created automatically during the Anaconda installation:

```
~$ conda activate   
(base): ~$ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
```

I have an existing virtual environment `py37-venv` within which I would like to use Pandas:

```
(base) ~/myproject$ source py37-venv/bin/activate
(py37-venv) (base) ~/myproject$ python
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul  4 2019, 11:23:49) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
>>> import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

How can I use Pandas (and other Anaconda packages) within my virtual environment. Do I need to install Anaconda again within my virtual env?

Following advise from similar posts did not help. e.g:

1. Create an Anaconda env: but my env was already existing before installing Anaconda.
2. Set 
   `export PATH="/myrootpath/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh:$PATH"` but getting the same result.
3. Copying: `/myrootpath/anaconda3/pkgs/pandas-0.24.2-py37he6710b0_0` to `myproject/py37-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas-0.24.2-py37he6710b0_0`

Comment: Do not mix virtualenv and conda. They are different solutions to a similar problem. Just create a conda environment with the dependencies that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your project doens't have any dependencies apart from what's already included in Anaconda, I'd imagine that you can just run your code without activating your virtualenv environment.

Other than that the easisest thing to do would be to create a new conda environment and install the dependencies of your project into the newly created env.

Anaconda is not just a collection of packages, it also comes with a command line tool called `conda`.

You can create a new environment with conda like this `conda create -n <env_name> python=3.7` Then activate the new env with `conda activate <env_name>` and install any packages you need with `conda install <package>` (note: this will install the package into the currently active env, which means that it'll install it to the root env if you don't have another env activated)

As a side note: you don't have to use conda to install packages in a conda env, pip works just as well. So if your project has a `requirements.txt` (or something similar) you can just run `pip install -r requirements.txt` inside your conda env.